# C# Add Times of multiple textboxes together

Tags: c#, addition, timespan

I am trying to add lap times together but I first must check if there is a value in the textbox and then proceed. How do I do this? The lap time is recorded like this: 01:29:30

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    TimeSpan Diff1 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap1TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff2 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap2TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff3 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap3TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff4 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap4imeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff5 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap5TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff6 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap6TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff7 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap7TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff8 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap8TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff9 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap9TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Diff10 = TimeSpan.Parse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text);
    TimeSpan Total = Diff1 + Diff2 + Diff3 + Diff4 + Diff5 + Diff6 + diff7 + Diff8 + Diff9 + Diff10;
    fullTimeTextBox.Text = Total.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: `if(lap1TimeTextBox.Text != string.Empty)` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following approach using [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e(v=vs.110).aspx) and a `TimeSpan[]`:

```
TimeSpan[] laps = new TimeSpan[10];
bool valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap1TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[0]);
valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap2TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[1]);
// ...
valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[9]);

TimeSpan totalLaps = TimeSpan.Zero;
foreach (TimeSpan lap in laps)
    totalLaps = totalLaps + lap;
```

That works since a `TimeSpan` is a struct and cannot be `null`. All in the array are initialized with [`TimeSpan.Zero`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.zero(v=vs.110).aspx). So all non-parsable timespans will count as zero.

I have tested it successfully with some sample values in your format.

---

If you have plenty of such controls it might get tedious to repeat `TimeSpan.TryParse(lap1TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[0])` for every control even if is very easy, readable and testable code.

If those `TextBoxes` are all in the same container-control (like a `Panel` or the form) you could use folllowing LINQ approach:

```
TimeSpan sumOfAllLapTimes = LapTimePanel.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    .Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("lap", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .Select(txt => txt.Text.TryGetTimeSpan())
    .Where(ts => ts.HasValue)
    .Select(ts => ts.Value)
    .Sum();
```

This query uses following two handy extension methods:

```
public static TimeSpan? TryGetTimeSpan(this string timeSpan, IFormatProvider formatProvider = null)
{
    if (timeSpan == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("timeSpan");
    TimeSpan ts;
    bool success = TimeSpan.TryParse(timeSpan, formatProvider, out ts);
    if (success) return ts;
    return null;
}

public static TimeSpan Sum(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> timeSpans)
{
    TimeSpan sum = TimeSpan.Zero;
    foreach (TimeSpan ts in timeSpans) sum = sum + ts;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I personally dislike the idea of not using REUSE paradigm of OOP here. What if we have 1000 or 10000 TimeSpans here ?

Comment: @Fabjan, that would create a nice UI

Comment: At least not by me :)

Comment: I think it is somebody that has had a really bad experience with `TryParse`.

Comment: @Fabjan: then you have serious problems beyond this issue. Never have a gui with 1000 input-controls. Also, OP hasn't mentioned it and didn't want to optimize that part. The essential part is that using `TimeSpan.TryParse` handles all possible valid/invalid input and that a `TimeSpan` always has a value, so you can use it in an array safely without needing to initialize them in the case of invalid input. While LINQ might be appropriate it also introduces a logic that is not verified by OP. It could be that `lap11TimeTextBox` (if available) should not be counted.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I did not mean literally 1000 or 10000 i just wanted to point that if you do one operation 10 times - it already worth the effort to create method and reuse it.

Comment: @Fabjan: but why should i optimize something that is not an issue in the concrete case? If you have few controls (10 is still few) it's not always the best approach to determine them via LINQ, loops or even reflection. Using already available variables have  advantages: f.e. compile time safety and explicit code. OP also didnt mention that he wants to reduce line number but to handle invalid input and to sum up the valid timespans.

Comment: Because your of this problem has 10 lines of code with same operation like: valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[0]); valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[1]); valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[2]); valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[3]); valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[4]); valid = TimeSpan.TryParse(lap10TimeTextBox.Text, out laps[5]);  Does it look like a piece of good optimized code to you ?

Comment: I downvoted as well. It will work and could illustrate the core method of an answer, but you would end up with a loop.

Comment: @Fabjan: it looks like code which is very readable and easy to understand and which you can test and debug easily.If you remove a TextBox or rename it you get a compiler error which is desired.

Comment: @Fabjan: for what it's worth, i have added another approach which is probably what you think about.

Comment: @TimSchmelter now it is much better

Comment: Yes. I knew you could do it!

Comment: @GvS, not `TryParse` as such, more the `out` parameter anti-pattern.Sneaking values out of a function via its parameters is not so much a code-smell as a code asphyxiation. I'll always downvote any answer that suggests using it.

Answer (score 2):

I would put all listboxes in an array, and iterate through them, to minimize the repeating of code:

```
   TextBox[] boxes = { lap1TimeTextBox, lap2TimeTextBox, lap3TimeTextBox }; // etc
   // Get boxes with a value
   var filledBoxes = boxes.Where(b => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b.Text)); 

   // Extract timings
   var times = filledBoxes.Select(b => TimeSpan.Parse(b.Text));

   // Calculate the sum, use ticks, because Sum might not work on TimeSpan directly
   var sum = new TimeSpan(times.Sum(time => time.Ticks));
```

You can do this in one line, but that would make the code less readable.

Comment: Better use `TimeSpan.TryParse` instead of `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(b.Text)`. An empty string is not the only wrong possible user-input.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, that would be stealing the TryParse idea from another answerer. But in production code, I would first check for empty and then use TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create method for this purpose:

```
TimeSpan SumAll(params TextBox[] lapTimeTextBoxes)
{
    TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan();
    TimeSpan temp = new TimeSpan();
    for(int i = 1; i < lapTimeTextBoxes.Length; i++)
    {
       if(TimeSpan.TryParse(lap6TimeTextBox.Text, Temp)) result += temp;
    }
    return result;            
}
```

Use it like :

```
fullTimeTextBox.Text = SumAll(lap1TimeTextBox, lap2TimeTextBox, lap3TimeTextBox, lap4TimeTextBox, 
lap5TimeTextBox, lap6TimeTextBox, lap7TimeTextBox, lap8TimeTextBox, lap9TimeTextBox, lap10TimeTextBox).ToString();
```

Comment: We have 10 TimeSpans here not one and it's not about only solving the problem we face but it's also about being able to re-use this solution later...

Comment: @TimSchmelter It takes textboxes because we work with TextBox.Text property in our TryParse method right ? You're correct about returnin IEnumerable<TimeSpan> but this problem was (quote from TS) "just to add lap times together"... The main difference between this approach and the one you used is that this uses separate method to solve the task and it can be re-used later in case if TS wants to perform this operation again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter is it possible for you to have your opinion on this one and for me to have mine ? :)))  In my opinion it's not the best of your answers here but many of others i appreciated. So let's close this topic...

Comment: I really dislike your use of `params` and passing a variable number of parameters into methods. However, I'm so perplexed by @TimSchmelter's "Do you really create a new method for all things that you probably only need once?" question that I'm upvoting to show solidarity against the utterly incomprehensible "only create a method if it can be re-used" (non)logic.

Comment: @DavidArno: removed comments but its still my opinion that a method is useful only if you need it more than once, otherwise its just less readable because you always have to look into that method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter We are in danger of a "religious war" here for, IMO, the cases where taking 2+ lines of code and splitting them out into another method doesn't improve readability lie in the deepest recesses of edge cases. Time to move on...

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
TextBox[] timeTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(txt => txt.Name.StartsWith("lap")).ToArray();

TimeSpan totalTime = new TimeSpan();
foreach (TextBox txt in timeTextBoxes)
{
    TimeSpan time;
    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(txt.Text, out time))
        totalTime = totalTime.Add(time);
}

fullTimeTextBox.Text = totalTime.ToString();
```

Comment: I was wondering why this got downvoted, it works perfectly :)